# How to append a list from QLineEdit with iterations (only last value is showing)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I think I am missing a basic idea and structure in this problem.

I used QTDesigner 4 to design a UI for pyqt5.  In this UI the user will input a number into a QLineEdit widget named self.elaexpect and a second number into a second QLineEdit widget named self.elaact.  The user will then click a pushbutton named addnew.  The button then sends the information to a QTableWidget in the same Ui window (MainWindow).  This is all working as intended.  My trouble lies in the next desired outcome.

I would like to have the numbers then divide (expected/actual) to form a ratio, which is then stored in a list (not part of the Ui).  After this step I want to have the program find the average in a percentage. So, in math terms, it will look something like {[(Expected/Actual)+(Expected2+Actual2)]/2}*100.  This result will populate a QTextBrowser with a line stating what the percentage is.

My roadblock is attempting to have the ratios stored in a list.  As you'll see in my code, I have tried to use list.append() to no avail, storing it in  a for loop.  I've also tried to use copy.deepcopy after reading that I needed to append a copy of the list. What happens when I build the code is that the Ui opens, I input my numbers, and the interpreter processes the ratio and prints the ratio. Then I enter two more numbers and press the button, the interpreter processes this ratio and prints, but instead of having two numbers, I get only the last one.  I'm stuck here and have spent about 10 hours attempting different solutions, but can't shake the feeling that I am missing something basic.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import copy
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from app3 import Ui_MainWindow

class Accapp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)        
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.retranslateUi(self)
    self.elaaddnew.clicked.connect(self.elaaddRow)

     def elaaddRow(self):
    # Retrieve text from QLineEdit
    eladate = self.eladate.text()
    elatname = self.elaname.text()
    elaexpect = self.elaexp.text()
    elaactual = self.elaact.text()
    # Create a empty row at bottom of table
    numRows = self.elatable.rowCount()
    self.elatable.insertRow(numRows)
# Add text to the row
    self.elatable.setItem(numRows, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(eladate))
    self.elatable.setItem(numRows, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(elatname))
    self.elatable.setItem(numRows, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(elaexpect))
    self.elatable.setItem(numRows, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(elaactual))
# divide expected and actual times for ratio
    elaratio= int(elaexpect)/int(elaactual)
# convert ratio to string
    elaratiostr = str(elaratio)
#Split string to enter into list
    elastrsp = elaratiostr.split()
# Create list
    elaratiolst = []
#Create deepcopy of list
    elaratiolstc = copy.deepcopy(elaratiolst)
#append values into list 
    for x in elastrsp:
      elaratiolstc.append(x)
#Print list in python interpreter (not Ui)
    print(elaratiolstc)




if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Accapp()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the relevant part from the Ui (in reality it is properly aligned):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1044, 936)
        self.elatab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.elatab.setObjectName("elatab")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.elatab)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.elagrpbx = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.elatab)
        self.elagrpbx.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(994, 812))
        self.elagrpbx.setTitle("")
        self.elagrpbx.setObjectName("elagrpbx")
        self.formLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.elagrpbx)
        self.formLayout_3.setObjectName("formLayout_3")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.elaname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.elagrpbx)
        self.elaname.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(78, 20))
    self.elaname.setObjectName("elaname")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elaname)
    self.label_35 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.elagrpbx)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label_35.setFont(font)
    self.label_35.setObjectName("label_35")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_35)
    self.elaexp = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.elagrpbx)
    self.elaexp.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(78, 20))
    self.elaexp.setObjectName("elaexp")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elaexp)
    self.elaaddnew = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.elagrpbx)
    self.elaaddnew.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 23))
    self.elaaddnew.setObjectName("elaaddnew")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elaaddnew)
    self.eladate = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.elagrpbx)
    self.eladate.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(79, 22))
    self.eladate.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate(2018, 9, 14))
    self.eladate.setObjectName("eladate")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.eladate)
    self.label_33 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.elagrpbx)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label_33.setFont(font)
    self.label_33.setObjectName("label_33")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_33)
    self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.elagrpbx)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label_34.setFont(font)
    self.label_34.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_34.setWordWrap(True)
    self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_34)
    self.label_36 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.elagrpbx)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label_36.setFont(font)
    self.label_36.setObjectName("label_36")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_36)
    self.elaact = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.elagrpbx)
    self.elaact.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(78, 20))
    self.elaact.setObjectName("elaact")
    self.formLayout_2.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elaact)
    self.formLayout_3.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.formLayout_2)
    self.elatable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.elagrpbx)
    self.elatable.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(729, 600))
    self.elatable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(729, 619))
    self.elatable.setObjectName("elatable")
    self.elatable.setColumnCount(4)
    self.elatable.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.elatable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.elatable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.elatable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.elatable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    self.elatable.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(175)
    self.elatable.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
    self.elatable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(46)
    self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elatable)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer was a simple fix as expected, thanks to u/Thomasedv on the r/learnpython subreddit.  Solution was to include:

```
self.ratio_list=[]
```

in the `__init__` class then add

```
self.ratio_list.append(elaratio)
```

in elaaddrow.

This solved the problem.